# How to process asynchronously fetched data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope

I'm new to AngularJS and am struggling with how to process the data fetched asynchronously from the server before displaying it on the page.

The data I'm fetching is like this:

```
"all_colors":[
      {"color":"red","quantity":1},
      {"color":"green","quantity":11},
      {"color":"yellow","quantity":5}
]
```

When the page loads initially I fetch the above data from the server like this:

```
angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
.controller('DashbordCtrl', function ($scope, djangoAuth, Validate, $location) {
  djangoAuth.fetch_from_server().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
  });
```

I would like to show two things on the page:

```
Available Colors: 3
Total Color Quantity: 17
```

I can show the available colors like this:

```
Available Colors: {{model.all_colors.length}}
```

**Question**

But how can I loop the all_colors and count the quantity for each so that I can show `Total Color Quantity` ?

I can't seem to do this in my JS file after fetching the data because it is fetched asynchronously. I can't figure out the way to do this.

Comment: Does `fetch_from_server()` return a promise? Are you using `$q`?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker `fetch_from_server()` is exactly similar to this file https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth/blob/master/app/scripts/services/djangoAuth.js#L130

Comment: You'll need to loop over the values of quantity. angular.foreach will help for this. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach add them to an array and return the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of how you obtain the data, just think about what data you need to display - your ViewModel - and assign values to them, if and when you obtain the data.

In this case, create a scope-exposed property `$scope.totalColorQty`, and assign its value when you receive the data:

```
djangoAuth.fetch_from_server().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
    $scope.totalColorQty = computeColorQuantity(data.all_colors);
});

function computeColorQuantity(colorsArray){
  // do whatever you need to calculate the quantity
}
```

Then, simply display it in the UI:

```
<div>Total Color Quantity: 
   <span ng-show="totalColorQty === undefined">Loading...</span>
   <span ng-hide="totalColorQty === undefined">{{totalColorQty}}</span>
</div>
```

Few additional notes:

1) You *could* expose `computeColorQuantity` on the scope and bind to that. But, I strongly recommend against that - since this operation is "heavy" and will be performed on every digest cycle, making your entire app slower.

DON'T DO THIS:

```
<div> Total Color Quantity: {{computeColorQuantity(model.all_colors)}}</div>
```

2) If you don't need to recalculate this value, then you could bind-once to reduce the number of $watchers:

```
<span ng-show="totalColorQty">{{::totalColorQty}}</span>
```

3) If you do intend to allow users to update the data, then I suggest to recalculate it on every user-initiated changed, for example, via `ng-change`, instead of via deep $watch

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. For now, I'm going with the `computeColorQuantity ` approach you suggested. While I wont do 1) I don't understand what 2) and 3) mean since its my second day with AngularJs. I do expect this data to be constantly changing as users make requests.

Comment: Don't worry about (2). (3) only applies if you intend to show the data in a form and have users edit it on the page. If the data only changes via async fetching, then recalculating `totalColorQty` every time the data is fetched would suffice.